# How do I remove the grey background for dashed lines in a dojo line chart?

Tags: charts, dojo, linechart

I created a chart in Dojo using dashed and dotted lines.
Everything works fine except that the background of the dotted line is grey.

How do I remove the grey background of the line?

```
var xChart = new dojox.charting.Chart2D("test-chart");
xChart.setTheme(dojox.charting.themes.Julie);
xChart.addAxis("x");
xChart.addPlot("default", {type: "Lines"});

xChart.addSeries("xscsd", [2,3,5,5,23,1,6],
   {stroke: {color: "red", width: 1.5, style:"Dot"}});

xChart.render();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default theme defines a grey outline.  Override the outline with null when adding the series.

```
xChart.addSeries("xscsd", [2,3,5,5,23,1,6],
                 {stroke: {color: "red", width: 1.5, style:"Dot"},
                     outline: null });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cswing/qDL79/